# How do I access a result set from a stored procedure in another stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a non-trivial `SELECT` statement and I don't want to write it twice (standard SW development considerations). I want to use the results in two stored procedures. I am imagining something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE consumerProcedureA()
BEGIN
    CALL supplierProcedure();
    -- ** insert magic here **
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE consumerProcedureB()
BEGIN
    CALL supplierProcedure();
    -- ** insert magic here **
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE supplierProcedure()
BEGIN
    SELECT field1, field2, field3, MESSYEXPR AS field4
    FROM (complicated sub-SQL query) -- blah blah blah
    ;
END;
```

Grant you, I could create a view to capture the common query, but is there a way to have a calling stored procedure access and process the result set returned by a called stored procedure?

Answer (score 3):

I am looking for a way to do this myself (in a way that satisfies me..), but a perfectly valid way to do so is described in this Stack Overflow Q & A:

[Calling a Stored Procedure in a Stored Procedure in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11000802)

The accepted answer by [AhamedMustafaM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384784/ahamedmustafam) demonstrates a technique using `OUT` parameters with the following code:

> ```
>     CREATE PROCEDURE innerproc(OUT param1 INT)
>     BEGIN
>      insert into sometable;
>      SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() into param1 ;
>     END
>     -----------------------------------
>     CREATE PROCEDURE outerproc()
>     BEGIN
>     CALL innerproc(@a);
>     // @a gives you the result of innerproc
>     SELECT @a INTO variableinouterproc FROM dual;
>     END
> ```

I'm sure not always the answer for what you are trying to accomplish, but it is certainly an option. While you couldn't get the *direct* result of what the procedure called, this would help you get individual values, possibly using multiple `OUT` parameters to get what you need.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to gain access to a conceptual list to iterate through. This could be used as a key to a table whose relevant entries all have that key, I grant you - but that goes back to the early notes. I also grant that if I reduced my requirements to a fixed length tuple, your technique would be applicable. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The title of the question clearly says "result SET"...

Comment: `SELECT @a INTO variableinouterproc FROM dual;` - correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the `DUAL` table an Oracle construct?

Answer (score 2):

you have to be a little tricky at this point.

first you create a temporary table for your select, this happens in the example in

```
CALL my_procedure():
```

Then   you can use that temporary table and use it in your query, and finally you can DROP the temporary table.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  fullname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  something VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO example (id, fullname, email, something) VALUES
  (1, 'Name 1', 'name1@example.com', 'Something 1'),
  (2, 'Name 2', '', 'Something 2'),
  (3, 'Name 1', 'name1@example.com', 'Something 3'),
  (4, 'Name 3', 'name3@example.com', 'Something 4'),
  (5, 'Name 3', 'name3@example.com', 'Something 5'),
  (6, 'Name 4', '', 'Something 6');
  
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure ()
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_tbl 
    SELECT MAX(fullname), email 
    FROM example 
    GROUP BY email ;
END $$
delimiter ;

delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure2 ()
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM new_tbl;
   
  END $$
delimiter ;
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure3 ()
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM new_tbl;
   #DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS new_tbl;
  END $$
delimiter ;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
CALL my_procedure();
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
call my_procedure2();

| MAX(fullname) | email             |
| ------------- | ----------------- |
| Name 1        | name1@example.com |
| Name 4        |                   |
| Name 3        | name3@example.com |
```

---

**Query #3**

```
call my_procedure3();

| MAX(fullname) | email             |
| ------------- | ----------------- |
| Name 1        | name1@example.com |
| Name 4        |                   |
| Name 3        | name3@example.com |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/8)

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Although not perfect, I guess this will do.

Comment: What is the difference between procedure 2 and 3?

Comment: there is no difference it only shows that you can use the temporary table for more than one procedure